# how to make changes to one table in onupgrade method of database of five tables ignoring the rest in oncreate method

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have five tables in my sqlite db, the five tables are created in oncreate method if I make changes to one  table in upgrade method based on the previous db version when I launched the app the changes are made I can see through my logcat but it calls oncreate method and say the 4 tables already exist. How can I handle this error?

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old, int current_version) {

    if (version_old < 3) {
        database.execSQL(queryFive);
    }
```

`on onCreate` I have statements that creates table initially which is then called again after onUpgrade and triggering the error they already exist. How can I handle this? Thanks.

Comment: what are you passing in `queryFive` ?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you make changes in one table, you should increment the `DATABASE_VERSION` = 1,2,3 and so on.
2. Whenever changes are done in database, you should first drop (delete) all table and create them again.

   ```
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
       db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME); // drop table(s),if you have five tables , drop all five 
       onCreate(db); // this will create all tables again
   }
   ```

> Update : in case of not loosing old data of other tables

You need an abstract class that implements the upgrade process described here. Then you extend this abstract class for each of your tables. In your abstract class you must store you tables in a way(list, hardcoded) so when the onUpgrade fires you iterate over the table items and for each table item you do the described steps. They will be self upgraded, keeping all their existing details. Please note that the onUpgrade event fires only once per database, that's why you need to iterate over all your tables to do the upgrade of all of them. You maintain only 1 version number over all the database.

- beginTransaction
- run a table creation with `if not exists` (we are doing an upgrade, so the table might not exists yet, it will fail alter and drop)
- put in a list the existing columns `List<String> columns = DBUtils.GetColumns(db, TableName);`
- backup table (`ALTER table " + TableName + " RENAME TO 'temp_"                    + TableName`)
- create new table (the newest table creation schema)
- get the intersection with the new columns, this time columns taken from the upgraded table (`columns.retainAll(DBUtils.GetColumns(db, TableName));`)
- restore data (`String cols = StringUtils.join(columns, ",");
              db.execSQL(String.format(
                      "INSERT INTO %s (%s) SELECT %s from temp_%s",
                      TableName, cols, cols, TableName));`
  )
- remove backup table (`DROP table 'temp_" + TableName`)
- setTransactionSuccessful

other than that, there is not way you can achieve this. unless, you can create separate db file for each table.

Comment: i don't want loose the data in the other tables, you dnt seems to get my point on onupgrade i want to still have intact data in the tables created initially

Comment: you can try alternative that i added.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this looks very complicated is there any example i can find online . i tried commenting out the oncreate method in d db but new users wont have those initial table